# Return page/block number where string was found using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file that's structured like this...

```
--- Page 01 ---
blah blahblah
blahblahblah
--- Page 01 ---
--- Page 02 ---
blah asdf svlah
blahblahsafblah
--- Page 02 ---
--- Page 03 ---
nothing here
--- Page 03 ---
```

I would like a way to find the page number(s) a the keyword `blah` appears in, regardless of the frequency.

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

EDIT:
I've found the following oneliner that appears to do the trick but the output has empty lines. What it wrong with it? If I remove the `\n` I get a long string of numbers... :(

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /blah/ .. /--- Page (\d+)/'
```

Output:

```
01


02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is, from the first match of 'blah' it is satisfying all the lines until it finds the 'Page (\d+)'.

Try this:

```
    perl -ne 'print "$1$2" if /blah/ .. /--- Page (\d+) ---(\n)/'
```

Comment: Yes yours works. So does `perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while /blah.*?--- Page (\d+)/gs'` which is what I found out on my own.